# Compatibilty AES-256-CBC Node / Laravel

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, ssl, encryption

I'm trying to create a hash that is compatible with Laravel's Encryption module.
Here is the reference source code for Laravel: https://github.com/illuminate/encryption/blob/master/Encrypter.php#L101-163

Here is what I've come through:

```
const encrypt = function (payload) {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const key = new Buffer(config.stuff.key, 'base64');

    const cipher  = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    cipher.setAutoPadding(false); // With or without this /!\
    let value = cipher.update(serialize(JSON.stringify(payload)), 'utf8', 'base64');

    value + cipher.final('base64');

    const mac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', new Buffer(config.stuff.key, 'base64')).update(iv.toString('base64') + value).digest('hex');

    const json = JSON.stringify({ iv: iv.toString('base64'), value, mac });

    return base64_encode(json);
};
```

Unfortunately, I have a BAD_DECRYPT when I try that. This seems to come from OpenSSL's padding. Does anyone have an idea ?

Comment: Note: I have base64_encode and serialize functions utilities from phpjs and other stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
const encrypt = function (payload) {
    const iv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
    const key = new Buffer(config.stuff.key, 'base64');

    const cipher  = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
    let value = cipher.update(serialize(payload), 'utf8');

    value = Buffer.concat([value, cipher.final()]).toString('base64');

    const mac = crypto.createHmac('sha256', key)
            .update(iv.toString('base64') + value)
            .digest('hex');

    const json = JSON.stringify({ 
        iv: iv.toString('base64'), 
        value: value, 
        mac: mac 
    });

    return base64_encode(json);
};
```

The issues:

- `openssl_encrypt` automatically uses PKCS#7 padding and node.js does, too.
- Concatenating multiple Base64 strings to form a single Base64-encoded string will not always work, because the first of the two strings may contain padding characters (`=`) which means that not all bits of the previous character actually belong to the ciphertext. Some of them are just dummy bits. That's how Base64 works.

---

PHP's `serizalize` can be ported to JavaScript as seen [here](http://locutus.io/php/var/serialize/).

Comment: I forgot to note that I have serialize and other php functions. I'll try your solution asap

Comment: That works, awesome. The only thing is that it's `Buffer.concat([value, cipher.final()])`

Comment: Thanks! I usually don't actually try what I write in answers and now it has bitten me in the ass ;)